# Permission denied when running gitosis-init

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm trying to use [gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis) `https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis`
And I do this as the setting up section in its README.md.

When I input `sudo -H -u git gitosis-init </.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, the error message show like this:

`fatal: cannot copy '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/templates/admin/hooks/post-update' to '/srv/pspms/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update': Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 138, in handle_args
    user=user,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 75, in init_admin_repository
    template=resource_filename('gitosis.templates', 'admin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/repository.py", line 66, in init
    raise GitInitError('exit status %d' % returncode)
gitosis.repository.GitInitError: exit status 128`

It seems I haven't perimssion to copy file to the git `HOME` directory? But I use the command `sudo`.

Comment: Why gitosis, which is dead since 2009, and not gitolite? (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)

Comment: @VonC I want to deploy a git server, and I find gitosis, I'll check gitolite, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your user `git` doesn't have access to one of the directories in the following log output:

```
fatal: cannot copy '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/templates/admin/hooks/post-update' to '/srv/pspms/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update': Permission denied
```

Run `ls -la /srv/pspms/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git` and make sure your git user can access that directory, and the same for `/srv/pspms/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git`.